# Getting `which-func-mode` output as a string in Emacs lisp

Tags: emacs

I am trying to retrieve the output `which-function-mode` as a string in Emacs. I am going to create a keyboard binding shortcut that copies it to my clipboard.

It seems like this `(which-func-mode ("" which-func-format " "))` is used to insert which-function into Emacs header line. However, I can't seem to get this output as a string or retrieve it in any way. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on the mode.

Any ideas for how to get the output of `which-func-mode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (which-function)
>
> Return current function name based on point.

so to copy it to the clipboard, try

```
(defun my-copy-function-name ()
  "Put name of function at point to kill-ring."
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (which-function)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Where did you find the docs for `which-function-mode`?

Comment: After enabling `which-function-mode`, I used `C-h f` to search functions provided by which-function-mode and I found the `which-function` function, then read it's docstring using `C-h f` as well.